# 7zip - don't create zip file if file list is empty

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, 7-zip

I want to create an archive from *.txt files with 7zip. If there's no match for *.txt, no zip file should be created instead of any empty (22 bytes) zip file.

```
7z.exe a -sdel myarchive.zip *.txt
```

(I want the txt files deleted after the archive is created)

This would be run from a scheduled batch file, so when there are no txt files, I don't want to get an empty zip file.

Is there any swtich or option for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `7Z` command in an `IF EXIST...` statement:

```
IF EXIST *.TXT (7z.exe a -sdel myarchive.zip *.txt)
```

See [SS64 on `IF`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)

Comment: After all, this is a good solution! I expected some hidden 7z switch or something, but this works as well! Thanks!